# How to achieve jqgrid search overlay programatically

Tags: css, jqgrid

Can you tell me how can I show or hide search box overlay programatically using CSS.

Comment: Do you really mean "overlay" and not "dialog" or "form"? Searching dialog display overlay by default.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="search-box" />
<form>
```

CSS to hide:

```
.search-box{
    display:none;
}
```

CSS to show:

```
.search-box{
    display:block;
}
```